# WMTS Service security

Tags: wmts, security, configuration

I would like to implement service security for WMTS. I went through the GeoServer documentation. Didn't find anything useful. How can I implement this?

Comment: is that not considered a rest service? - https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/service.html#rest-services